# Product image is not showing up in poduct page where as showing list

Tags: image, magento, product

Magento product images are showing in list or grid. when i click on the product, the product image is not displaying in the product page. Remaining things Add to cart, Add to compare, wishlist everything is working fine. I think the media.phtml is not loading, Please suggest me in right way.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you must confirm whether the media.phtml is loaded. You may insert some dummy characters in the media.phtml to see whether it will show in the frontend.

Thus, if the characters show, congratulations, you are just close to find the problem. In this situation, most problems are caused by image attributes not loading to the model object. Simply just reload the object with the following snippets:

```
$_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_product->getId());
```

Otherwise, you may confirm the following things:

1. Is the *media.phtml* is overload by the other theme?
2. Compare with the default catalog.xml with your current one, to find out the *media.phtml* is correctly loaded, including path, block type, name, as, etc.
3. Check the permission settings for the xml and template files

These are stuffs coming to my mind when reading your problems. Hope it helps.